# Find Wordpress fastest loading site

Tags: html, wordpress, web, themes

I happened to visit this website and found it really really fast, it was like layers over layers but doesn't need to load the site at all, even once. Call me old but I'm really impressed by this technology:

```
https://www.bookofthemonth.com
```

If anyone knows what technique they're using here in this website please share. And furthermore, does Wordpress have any theme like this? For this site as a blog would be hard because it eventually needs to load and accumulate too many resources, true or false? It would be awesome if you can make a blog with articles on a site like this!(or at least that's what I'm looking for) Thanks everyone in advance.

Answer (score 2):

You can always do `View Source...` on an internet site you like.

If you do that to the site you mentioned, you'll find that it's a `react.js` site, not a site delivered by a standard cms such as WordPress.

Still, this site is a typical "single page" design, with

- a slider at the top
- row of information showing five interesting posts
- a row of hyperlinks (the How It Works) row
- a row of information showing five more interesting posts ("Meet our members")

You can certainly find several, or more, WordPress themes handling this.

It's also likely that the site for a recognized brand (like the one you mentioned) is delivered by a highly scalable web server infrastructure with caching and a content delivery network. So, can you make yours as fast as this?  Not without spending some serious money.

How to proceed?  Look for an appropriate "One Page" wordpress theme and follow the directions.

Once you get it looking correct, you can adopt Cloudflare or another content-delivery network platform.